# rhtml (eruby) apache trouble

Tags: ruby, apache, eruby

I am trying to run embedded ruby inside rhtml.

```
$cat test.rhtml

<html>
<body>
Testing <% foo = "Ruby"; print "#{foo}!" %>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine from the command line:

```
$eruby test.rhtml


<html>
<body>
Testing Ruby!
</body>
</html>
```

But inside my apache setup it doesn't work.

Accessing "http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.rhtml" gives following error:

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Error log says:

[Sat Jan 22 17:56:07 2011] [error] [client ::1] (8)Exec format error: exec of 'Dir/cgi-bin/test.rhtml' failed
[Sat Jan 22 17:56:07 2011] [error] [client ::1] Premature end of script headers: test.rhtml

I have copied "eruby" executable to "Dir/cgi-bin/" directory and configured apache (2.2) as follows:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-eruby .rhtml
Action application/x-httpd-eruby Dir/cgi-bin/eruby
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add, at a minimum,

```
Content-type: text/html

<html>
....
```

at the top of your eruby file -- CGI scripts are responsible for sending back headers to the client before the content. There may be more headers that make sense to send back, but this might be sufficient to get started.

Comment: Thanks! I added "Content-type" field but it still doesn't work.     $ cat test.rhtml 
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<body>
Testing <% foo = "Ruby"; print "#{foo}!" %> 
</body>
</html>
Getting the same error in error log. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the two newlines after text/html are required.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mark! I added two new lines but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have **Apache/2.2.22** on **Ubuntu 12.04** & **Ruby 1.8.7**. I installed the **erubis 2.7.0** implementation & copied the executable erubis file to Apache’s cgi folder, in my case to /usr/lib/cgi-bin/erubis. I configured a cgi script called erubis.sh to handle requests for .rhtml files by adding these directives to /etc/apache/httpd.conf:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-eruby .rhtml
Application application/x-httpd-eruby /cgi-bin/erubis.sh
```

I made sure that the Action module is enabled by running this command:

```
$ sudo a2enmod action
```

I created this bash shell script **erubis.sh** to handle requests for pages with embedded ruby:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo
echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"
erubis -E Stdout <$DOCUMENT_ROOT$REQUEST_URI
```

It outputs a minimal http header then asks erubis to process the requested .rhtml file containing embedded Ruby. The Stdout enhancement option seemed necessary to get the output of the embedded Ruby blocks in the right places.

http://techdog.tumblr.com/post/36496065877/configure-erubis-cgi-in-apache